# SortByColumns with multiple filters is only returning the latest 2000 items, although i am not getting any delegation warning

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp

I have this formula inside a canvas app Items property:-

```
SortByColumns(
    If(
        And(
            chkMyRequests.Value = true,
            IsBlank(ddStatus),
            IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
        ),
        Filter(
            
                'LogsRequests',
                
                (IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) ||Title = SearchBox.Text ||
                ISBN = SearchBox.Text) &&
                'Created By'.Email = User().Email
        ),
        If(
            And(
                chkMyRequests.Value = true,
                !IsBlank(ddStatus),
                IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
            ),
            Filter(
               
                    'LogsRequests',
                   
                  (IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) ||  Title =  SearchBox.Text ||
                    ISBN =  SearchBox.Text)&&
                
                'Created By'.Email = User().Email &&
                Status.Value = ddStatus.Selected.Value
            ),
            If(
                And(
                    chkMyRequests.Value = true,
                    !IsBlank(ddStatus),
                    !IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
                ),
                Filter(
                   
                        'LogsRequests',
                       
                       ( IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) || Title =  SearchBox.Text ||
                        ISBN =  SearchBox.Text) &&
                    
                    'Created By'.Email = User().Email &&
                    Status.Value = ddStatus.Selected.Value &&
                    Store = inpStores.Selected.'Full Store Name'
                ),
                If(
                    And(
                        chkMyRequests.Value = true,
                        IsBlank(ddStatus),
                        !IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
                    ),
                    Filter(
                       
                            'LogsRequests',
                          
                           ( IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) || Title =   SearchBox.Text ||
                        ISBN =  SearchBox.Text) 
                        &&
                        'Created By'.Email = User().Email &&
                        Store = inpStores.Selected.'Full Store Name'
                    ),
                    If(
                        And(
                            chkMyRequests.Value = false,
                            IsBlank(ddStatus),
                            !IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
                        ),
                        Filter(
                           
                                'LogsRequests',
                            
                            (IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) || Title   = SearchBox.Text ||
                             ISBN =   SearchBox.Text)
                           &&
                            Store = inpStores.Selected.'Full Store Name'
                        ),
                        If(
                            And(
                                chkMyRequests.Value = false,
                                !IsBlank(ddStatus),
                                IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
                            ),
                            Filter(
                               
                                    'LogsRequests',
                                    
                                   (IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) ||  Title = SearchBox.Text ||
                                    ISBN = SearchBox.Text)
                                &&
                                Status.Value = ddStatus.Selected.Value
                            ),
                            If(
                                And(
                                    chkMyRequests.Value = false,
                                    !IsBlank(ddStatus),
                                    !IsBlank(inpStores.Selected)
                                ),
                                Filter(
                                    
                                        'LogsRequests',
                                    
                                       (IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) || Title =  SearchBox.Text ||
                                        ISBN =  SearchBox.Text)
                                    &&
                                    Store = inpStores.Selected.'Full Store Name'&&
                                    Status.Value = ddStatus.Selected.Value
                                ),
                                Filter(
                                    'LogsRequests',
                                    IsBlank(SearchBox.Text) ||
                                    Title = SearchBox.Text ||
                                    ISBN = SearchBox.Text
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    "Created",
    SortOrder.Descending
)
```

now i am only getting 2000 items without getting the new items. so seems this formula is not delegable, although inside my power apps i am not getting any delegation warning. any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IsBlank() cannot delegate Choice, Lookup, Person or Group, Task Outcome, External Data, Managed Metadata,Text
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply,,, but in my case i did not get any delegation warning in design mode... it is weird correct?

Comment: Generally, formulas display a yellow exclamation mark sign to indicate that they are not delegable. It's possible that something unexpected happened. For questions about delegation, check out this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#power-apps-delegable-functions-and-operations-for-sharepoint

Comment: A formula such as Filter(..., IsBlank(CustomerId)) won't delegate to SharePoint. However, that formula is semantically close to Filter(..., CustomerId = Blank()), which will delegate to SharePoint. These formulas aren't equivalent because the second formula won't treat the empty string ("") as empty. However, the second formula might work for your purposes. On SharePoint, this approach will work for the equals operator ("=") but not the operator for not equals ("<>").